# Does it improve click through rate from Google if I put queries from search console into the page?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, meta-description, meta-keywords

I want to improve some pages' click-through rate (CTR). Someone suggested to me that I should add Google Search Console queries into keywords, meta description, h1, h2, etc.

Is that likely to work or are there more effective methods to improve CTR?

Comment: Google doesn't use meta keywords, so don't bother with that one.

Answer (score 1):

What's visible on a page can't directly affect CTR. People haven't seen it.

Indirectly it can change how you rank, and that can affect your CTR. E.g. If you rank higher or for searches that are more relevant.

Title tags and meta descritions can be used in your search result snippet. If that looks good to the searchers it can increase your CTR.

Comment: People could see it if Google chooses to use it in the snippet shown in the search results.   Google does tend to choose snippets that match the search query when it can.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller good point. Especially if it's text from the GSC and matches common searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement variations of those queries into your content to try this.
Optimize your Meta description for better ctr.